# Laravel. Каталог в папке public совпадает с роутем, как сделать чтоб срабатывал роут, а не открывался каталог?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

В каталоге public есть каталог books, так же у меня есть   `Route::get('books', 'BooksController@index');`
До того как появился каталог, все прекрасно работало. После этого стал открываться каталог с 403 ошибкой и в адресной строке стал отображаться полный путь     localhost/myapp/public/books. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение - переименовать роут или каталог, лучше даже каталог. 
Более сложное - зависит от цели и ситуации. Приведу 2 варианта.

1. В файле роута проверить урл на is_dir(), и регистрировать роут по другому урлу и использовать именование as.

   If(is_dir($books_path)) {
       Route::get("knigi", ["as" => "books", " uses" => Controller::class."@action"]);
   } else {
       Route::get("books", ["as" => "books", " uses" => Controller::class."@action"]);
   }
2. В экшене контроллера делать проверку на существование этого файла. И в помощь написать helper function. Общая логика такова: проверяешь хэлпером существует такой файл по урлу books/bulgakov-master-imargarita.jpg если тру, метод возвращает сам файл на просмотр, если нет - вьюху и общую логику.

Больше вариков я не вижу)) надеюсь помог))

U.P.D. сорри, я неверно прочитал вопрос))) но суть в том-же, только наоборот.)) правда, у тебя появиться в таком случае проблема с просмотром из этого каталога. Придется доп. Параметр в запросе передавать, который и будет определять - роут просмотреть или файл.